# Use python regex to find a value in a json

Tags: python, regex, linux, python-requests

Not sure if this is the fastest or best way to navigate a json, but im downloading it via requests. and have parsed to down to

```
['Average volume</span><div c', 'Average volume</span><span ', '10000","volume":"13458635.0', 'ernight_volume":"0.000000",', 'average_volume_2_weeks":"14', 'average_volume":"14172441.6', 'average_volume_30_days":"13', 'trading volume occurs durin']
```

but I only want the value for "volume". My knowledge of python is limited so plz so ez on me.

I was trying to do kinda like a `r'^'volume^''`
or a `r'\'volume\''` but neither work.

###MORE JSON BELOW

"quote":{"ask_price":"66.440000","ask_size":50,"venue_ask_time":"2023-08-01T21:19:44.648248045Z","bid_price":"66.110000","bid_size":50,"venue_bid_time":"2023-08-01T21:19:44.648248045Z","last_trade_price":"66.240000","venue_last_trade_time":"2023-08-01T19:59:59.570650825Z","last_extended_hours_trade_price":"66.250000","last_non_reg_trade_price":"66.250000","venue_last_non_reg_trade_time":"2023-08-01T20:09:58.711201369Z","previous_close":"67.070000","adjusted_previous_close":"67.070000","previous_close_date":"2023-07-31","symbol":"XLU","trading_halted":false,"has_traded":true,"last_trade_price_source":"nls","last_non_reg_trade_price_source":"consolidated","updated_at":"2023-08-01T21:19:44Z","instrument":"http://loadbalancer-marketdata.nginx.service.robinhood/instruments/b9fe8700-4fe3-4612-b857-7fbb81fd09a4/","instrument_id":"b9fe8700-4fe3-4612-b857-7fbb81fd09a4","state":"active"}

###Thatll do er bud

Comment: there was blackslashes in that second re pattern

Comment: It looks like your approach is broken before you have this list.

Comment: If you had `json` at some point, I might go back to that first. At the moment you have a list of strings.

Comment: Curious what this looks like before it was put into a list. That may be a more reasonable starting point than what you have now.

Comment: thing is, Im pulling the html with requests so, i dont think i can parse into json can i? like with Beautiful soup or anything?

Comment: ill post the html

Comment: You are getting a response back from requests. What is that response in its raw form? Is it HTML? Is it JSON? Is it something else? This is an odd mix of pieces of html and pieces of json. It doesn't seem right.

Comment: its a mix JNevil. Thanks.

Comment: @JNevill I hit it with one of these

Comment: import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime

SPYETFS = ['SPY','XLC','XLY','XLP','XLE','XLF','XLV','XLI','XLK','XLB','XLRE','XLU']
prices = []
date = []
DOTW = []
time = []

#___________________________________________________________________


for ETF in SPYETFS:
        url = "https://robinhood.com/us/en/stocks/"+ETF    
    
        response = requests.get(url)
    
        text = response.text

Comment: You definitely want to check out beautiful soup to grab that data from the html that is returned.

Comment: @JonSG tell me more bout this beautiful soup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very sketchy and I don't recommend this, but it does the job if your method of making the list is consistent enough. But I recommend checking out the json package instead of this.

```
L = ['Average volume</span><div c', 'Average volume</span><span ', '10000","volume":"13458635.0', 'ernight_volume":"0.000000",', 'average_volume_2_weeks":"14', 'average_volume":"14172441.6', 'average_volume_30_days":"13', 'trading volume occurs durin']
volume = float([x for x in L if '"volume":"' in x ][0].split('"')[-1])
print(volume)
```

edit: On second thought, doesn't seem like it's json to begin with, I agree with the commenters, it's probably an issue higher up the chain, your data should be more manageable at some earlier point. Maybe consider looking into that!

Comment: v chill thanks fren